# SQL Count within a Select

Tags: sql, count

I would like to display a gallery of photos and how many times each photo has been rated.

Here's my simply query but not sure how to get the Count from the Ratings table.

```
SELECT
   Photo.photoID
  ,Photo.photoName
  ,Member.memberID
  ,Member.memberFName
  ,Rating.ratingID
FROM
  Photo
INNER JOIN Member ON Photo.memberID = Member.memberID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Rating ON Photo.photoID = Rating.photoID
ORDER BY Photo.photoID DESC
```

Every time someone clicks the Star Rating buttons, a new record is inserted into the Rating table. I am only allowing a photo to be rated 100 times, therefore I would like to display the number of times a photo has been rated (i.e. 57/100) when the user is browsing the gallery.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the count function with a group by statement to get the count of ratings.

```
select p.photoID,
p.photoName,
m.memberID,
m.memberFName,
count(r.RatingID) as RatingCount
from Photo p
inner join Member m on p.memberID = m.memberID
left outer join Rating r on p.photoID = r.photoID
group by p.photoID, p.photoName, m.memberID, m.memberFName
```

Comment: Thank you both! COALESCE - that's a new one for me!

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.photoID,
    p.photoName,
    m.memberID,
    m.memberFName,
    coalesce(rc.Count, 0) as RatingCount
from Photo p
inner join Member m on p.memberID = m.memberID
left outer join (
    select photoID, count(*) as Count
    from Rating
    group by photoID
) rc on p.photoID = rc.photoID
order by p.photoID desc
```